# Jetpack Compose deferring reads in phases for performance

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Official article about [Jetpack Compose phases](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/phases) and this article about [deferring reads](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance#defer-reads) for performance suggests moving any state reads from `Composition` phase to `Layout` or `Draw` phases such as

`Modifier.offset()` which is read in `Composition` phase to
`Modifier.offset{}` which is read in `Layout` phase or

`Modifier.background()` to `Modifier.drawBehind{}` to defer read to `Draw` phase.

Based on the articles i created 2 separate samples.

For this created a Box that changes title color on each recomposition

```
@Composable
private fun MyBox(modifier: Modifier, title: String) {

    LogCompositions(msg = " MyBox() COMPOSITION $title")

    Column(modifier) {

        // This Text changes color on every recomposition
        Text(
            text = title,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(getRandomColor())
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(2.dp)
        )

        Text(
            text = "modifier hash: ${modifier.hashCode()}\n"
                    + "Modifier: $modifier",
            color = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier.heightIn(max = 120.dp),
            fontSize = 10.sp
        )
    }
}
```

function for generating color

```
fun getRandomColor() =  Color(
    red = Random.nextInt(256),
    green = Random.nextInt(256),
    blue = Random.nextInt(256),
    alpha = 255
)
```

Log recompositions

```
class Ref(var value: Int)

// Note the inline function below which ensures that this function is essentially
// copied at the call site to ensure that its logging only recompositions from the
// original call site.
@Composable
inline fun LogCompositions(msg: String) {
    val ref = remember { Ref(0) }
    SideEffect { ref.value++ }
    println("$msg, count: ${ref.value}")
}
```

First Sample

```
@Composable
private fun PhasesSample1() {

    LogCompositions(msg = "1️⃣ PhasesSample1")

    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Text(text = "OffsetX")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Slider(value = offsetX,
            valueRange = 0f..50f,
            onValueChange = {
                offsetX = it
            }
        )
    }

    val modifier1 = Modifier
        // Reads value directly
        .offset(x = offsetX.dp)
        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
            val placeable: Placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                println("️ modifier1 LAYOUT")
                placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            }
        }
        .background(Blue400)
        .drawWithContent {
            println(" modifier1 DRAW")
            drawContent()
        }


    val modifier2 = Modifier
        // Deferring state to Layout phase prevents
        // Composables that have this modifier to be recomposed
        .offset {
            val newX = offsetX.dp.roundToPx()
            IntOffset(newX, 0)
        }
        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
            val placeable: Placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                println(" modifier2 LAYOUT")
                placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            }
        }
        .background(Blue400)
        .drawWithContent {
            println(" modifier2 DRAW")
            drawContent()
        }

    MyBox(modifier = modifier1, "modifier1")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
    MyBox(modifier = modifier2, "modifier2")
}
```

This one works as expected. When i change offset with slider `modifier1` goes through
`Composition->Layout->Draw` phases since it has `Modifier.offset(x = offsetX.dp)`

`modifier2` calls `Layout` phase only, i thought it should call `Draw` too but it's not a major question, probably because it reads same color so it doesn't update `Draw` phase

Other sample is

```
@Composable
private fun PhasesSample2() {

    LogCompositions(msg = "2️⃣  PhasesSample2")

    // This state is for triggering recomposition for PhasesSample2,
    // child composables don't read this state
    var someValue by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Text(text = "someValue")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Slider(value = someValue,
            valueRange = 0f..50f,
            onValueChange = {
                someValue = it
            }
        )
    }

    val modifier3 = Modifier
        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
            val placeable: Placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                println(" modifier3 LAYOUT")
                placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            }
        }
         .drawWithContent {
            println(" modifier3 DRAW")
            drawRect(getRandomColor())
            drawContent()
        }

    val modifier4 = Modifier
        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
            val placeable: Placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                println("⚾️ modifier4 LAYOUT")
                placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            }
        }
        .drawWithContent {
            println(" modifier4 DRAW")
            drawContent()
        }
        //  reading color causes Composition->Layout->Draw
        .background(getRandomColor())

    MyBox(modifier = modifier3, "modifier3")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
    MyBox(modifier = modifier4, "modifier4")
}
```

Both Sample Composables are in a `Column`

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(8.dp)
) {
    PhasesSample1()
    Spacer(modifier =Modifier.height(20.dp))
    PhasesSample2()
}
```

If i move Slider in `PhasesSample1` Composable log is as

```
I/System.out: 1️⃣ PhasesSample1, recomposition: 1
I/System.out:  MyBox() COMPOSITION modifier1, recomposition: 1
I/System.out: ️ modifier1 LAYOUT
I/System.out:  modifier2 LAYOUT
I/System.out:  modifier1 DRAW
I/System.out:  modifier3 DRAW
I/System.out:  modifier4 DRAW
I/ViewRootImpl@159ca9[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/System.out: 1️⃣ PhasesSample1, recomposition: 2
I/System.out:  MyBox() COMPOSITION modifier1, recomposition: 2
I/System.out: ️ modifier1 LAYOUT
I/System.out:  modifier2 LAYOUT
I/System.out:  modifier1 DRAW
I/System.out:  modifier3 DRAW
I/System.out:  modifier4 DRAW
```

##### Question

Why `DRAW` phases of `modifier3` and `modifier4` are called when they are in a different Composable with scope? As you can see only `PhasesSample1` is **recomposed**.

If i move Slider in `PhasesSample2` Composable

```
I/System.out: 2️⃣  PhasesSample2, recomposition: 1
I/System.out:  MyBox() COMPOSITION modifier4, recomposition: 1
I/System.out: ⚾️ modifier4 LAYOUT
I/System.out:  modifier1 DRAW
I/System.out:  modifier3 DRAW
I/System.out:  modifier4 DRAW
I/System.out: 2️⃣  PhasesSample2, recomposition: 2
I/System.out:  MyBox() COMPOSITION modifier4, recomposition: 2
I/System.out: ⚾️ modifier4 LAYOUT
I/System.out:  modifier1 DRAW
I/System.out:  modifier3 DRAW
I/System.out:  modifier4 DRAW
```

**This time DRAW phase is invoked only modifier1 is called but not modifier2?**

This is how visually changes happen. Change of color of title, **section with modifierX on top**, is due to recomposition also Modifier hash code changes.

Background change when title doesn't change is due to calling `DRAW` state as you can verify from logs.

[image]