# Issue with jetpack compose animation performance

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, compose-recomposition

I am using `animateDpAsState` animation, but there is an issue with performance. The animation is very laggy, lot of frames are dropped. When I build application with release mode, animation is running more smoothly, but it is not as good as it needs to be.
Strange thing is that when I play animation several times (for example 15 times), animation is then very smooth and everything is ok.

What could be a problem?

My code:

```
           val contextMenuAnimation = animateDpAsState(
                targetValue =
                if (contextMenuOpened.value) -contextMenuWidth
                else 0.dp,
                animationSpec = tween()
            )
```

.
.
.

```
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(x = maxWidth + contextMenuAnimation.value)
                    .size(contextMenuWidth, height = maxHeight)
            ) {
                SidePanel()
            }
```

Comment: Post the code of your animated view, animation logic

Comment: I added code to question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One improvement you can have over your current setup is using `Modifier.offset{IntOffset}` over `Modifier.offset()`. Jetpack Compose has three phases Composition, Layout and Draw if you use Modifiers with lambda you can skip or defer reads as you can see in [official document](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#defer-reads). Using Modifiers with lambdas are advised with animations.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73274631/5457853

You can also check out scoped or smart recomposition to limit recomposition amount to Composable scopes.

[Jetpack Compose Smart Recomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257459/jetpack-compose-smart-recomposition)

And you still in need to improve performance that you think might happen due to recompositions you can check out these articles about stability/immutability

https://chris.banes.dev/posts/composable-metrics/

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-stability-explained-79c10db270c8

Comment: Tried Modifier.offset{IntOffset} and now everything is running very smoothly! Thank you so much!