# Unable to stop the Canvas Composable's draw scope from triggering continuously

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

I have a Box layout in which I have a canvas composable that draws a circle animation. I also have another Test Composable in which I would be drawing a few other shapes(Denoted in Grey color in the video attachment).

The problem I'm facing is every time the animation value animates the circle, the draw scope lambda inside the test composable function is also triggered continuously which I do not want. I put a print line to confirm it.

I'm unable to understand why the draw scope lambda of another composable is triggered. Any help in understanding this behavior and how not to make it trigger continuously is deeply appreciated.

```
Box(
 modifier = Modifier.
  .fillMaxWidth(1f)
 .wrapContentHeight()
) {
   BlinkingCircle()
   val modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
   Test(modifier)
}



@Composable
fun BlinkingCircle() {

val screenWidthInDp = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
val infiniteScale = rememberInfiniteTransition()
val animatableSize = infiniteScale.animateFloat(
    initialValue = 40f,
    targetValue = 6f,
    animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
        animation = tween(
            durationMillis = 1500,
            easing = FastOutLinearInEasing
        ),
        repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
    )
 )


val xStart = 57f
val yStart = 126f

Canvas(modifier = Modifier
    .width(screenWidthInDp.dp)
    .fillMaxHeight(1f),
    onDraw = {
        drawScope.drawCircle(
            color = Color.White,
            radius = animatableSize.value,
            center = Offset(
            x = xStart,
            y = yStart)
        )
     }
   )
}


@Composable
fun Test(modifier: Modifier) {
   Box(
    modifier = modifier
        .background(Color.LightGray)
        .width(150.dp)
        .height(100.dp)
        .offset(300.dp, 50.dp)
   ) {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier
        .width(50.dp)
        .height(50.dp),
        onDraw = {
            println("Testing Box Text - 2")
            //drawCircle(Color.Green, radius = 30f)
        })
     }
  }


2022-08-10 01:43:56.897 15718-15718/com.xxxx.dev I/System.out: Testing Box Text - 2
2022-08-10 01:43:56.911 15718-15718/com.xxxx.dev I/System.out: Testing Box Text - 2
2022-08-10 01:43:56.927 15718-15718/com.xxxx.dev I/System.out: Testing Box Text - 2
2022-08-10 01:43:56.946 15718-15718/com.xxxx.dev I/System.out: Testing Box Text - 2
2022-08-10 01:43:56.962 15718-15718/com.xxxx.dev I/System.out: Testing Box Text - 2
2022-08-10 01:43:56.979 15718-15718/com.xxxx.dev I/System.out: Testing Box Text - 2
....
....
```

[image]

[Video sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17AnNwo_bXv0OjwLDu9SHXNmEfKOs5hLh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I asked a similar question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457805/jetpack-compose-defering-reads-in-phases-for-performance When you trigger recomposition on a Composable  `draw` phase of another Composable inside different parent and scope is triggered. This is really strange and i don't know why it happens. Is it a bug or feature?

Comment: You can try wrapping `BlinkingCircle()` and `Test(modifier)` individually with another Composable, for instance with a Column. In the question when i wrapped each sample composable with Column they didn't trigger draw phase when other one is recomposed

Comment: I did the following though but still, the same behavior is exhibited.
` Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(1f)
                .wrapContentHeight()
        ) {
            val modifier = Modifier
            Test(modifier)
        }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(1f)
                .fillMaxHeight(1f)
        ) {
            BlinkingCircle(
                canvasWidth,
                bannersResponseItem.dataItemList ?: emptyList()
            )
        }
`

Comment: I don't know why this occurs, upvoted your question and if you come up with a solution please let me know

Comment: Thank you and Sure. I will raise this as a bug to the "compose team" in the issue tracker. Let's see if we could get a solution.