# Compose negative offset is not affecting it's actual size measurement

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to Compose and I would like to make a design like below.

The problem I am facing is when I set offset (y=-100) it is adjusting the start of the height but after the widget is moved I can still see the empty space. So it is not reflecting the widget's actual measurements.

[image]

Check below layout hierarchy snippets. I am using offset in the Card modifier.

```
Surface(){
        Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
         HorizontalPager() { 
                        ...................
                Image(
                    painterResource(currentImage.value),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
                }
            }
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier.offset(0.dp, (-100).dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 24.dp)
            ) {
     
                Column {
                    .......
                }
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))

            LazyRow(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp, bottom = 16.dp)) {
                items(10) {
                    Card {
                        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
                           ..........
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As mentioned in the docs, "Applying an offset only changes the position of the content, without interfering with its size measurement." Offset is done at the rendering phase after measurement. To achieve the required view, you can try wrapping the `Card` and `HorizontalPager` in a constraint layout.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Abhimanyu but I am new to compose and not sure how to use constraint layout. If you could assist me that would be a great help.

Comment: Also, Constraint layout docs mention that we can also achieve a "Guideline feature" using Spacer+Column.

Comment: @Abhimanyu you are right as in docs says it doesn't interfere with measurement because it calls `placeWithLayer` or `placeRelativeWithLayer` but offset is not done in rendering or draw phase. It's done in graphicsLayer in layout phase after measurement and layout is done. Check out my question and comment about `modifier2` the one with `Modifier.offset` calling only `layout` phase. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457805/jetpack-compose-deferring-reads-in-phases-for-performance

Comment: @ArpitPatel be careful when using ConstraintLayout, especially with complex layouts. Cmd + click ContraintLayout description then `MultiMeasureLayout` and you will see deprecation message `"This API is unsafe for UI performance at scale - using it incorrectly will lead " +
        "to exponential performance issues. This API should be avoided whenever possible."`

Comment: That's why i never use ConstraintLayout to face unexpected performance issues. Unlike View ConstraintLayout doesn't offer performance like it does over ViewGroups. `In the View system, ConstraintLayout was the recommended way to create large and complex layouts, as a flat view hierarchy was better for performance than nested views are. However, this is not a concern in Compose, which is able to efficiently handle deep layout hierarchies.`

Comment: @Thracian Thank you for pointing this out. The constraint Layout is working as expected but I am curious that how can I achieve a similar layout using Rows & columns & Spacer. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learn the Constraint layout quickly and figured out how I can apply guidelines in compose.

[Full Project Here](https://github.com/arpit999/ComposeDemo/tree/viewpager_with_dynamic_theme)

It is easy to apply constraints in a Constraint Layout. For those of you who don't know how to implement constraint layout, I am giving you a quick guide.

1. Create Constraint Layout

> ```
>  ConstraintLayout() {
> ...... Add your widgets here 
>      }
> ```

2. Define Constraint references & GuideLine within the constraint layout

> ```
> val startGuideline = createGuidelineFromTop(0.25f)
> val (viewPager, accountList, spacer, insightCards) = createRefs()
> ```

3. Apply constraints using `Modifier.constrainAs()`

> 

```
Modifier.constrainAs(accountList) {
                            start.linkTo(parent.start)
                            top.linkTo(startGuideline)
                        }
```

In My case, I need four constraints so I just declare four references and provide constraints to those.

Here is the complete snippet of my compose layout

```
 @OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun MyApp() {

        val imageList = listOf(R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f)

        val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
        val currentImage = remember(pagerState) { mutableStateOf(R.drawable.a) }
        val scroll = rememberScrollState()
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            color = Color(0xFF546E7A)
        ) {

            ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scroll)) {

                // Create guideline from the top of the parent at 20% the height of the Composable
                val startGuideline = createGuidelineFromTop(0.2f)
                val (viewPager, accountList, spacer, insightCards) = createRefs()

                HorizontalPager(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .constrainAs(viewPager) {
                            start.linkTo(parent.start)
                            top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        },
                    count = imageList.size, state = pagerState
                ) { page ->
                    when (page) {
                        0 -> currentImage.value = imageList[0]
                        1 -> currentImage.value = imageList[1]
                        2 -> currentImage.value = imageList[2]
                        3 -> currentImage.value = imageList[3]
                        4 -> currentImage.value = imageList[4]
                        5 -> currentImage.value = imageList[5]
                        else -> currentImage.value = R.drawable.a
                    }
                    Image(
                        painterResource(currentImage.value),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                        contentDescription = "",
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    )
                }

                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .constrainAs(accountList) {
                            start.linkTo(parent.start)
                            top.linkTo(startGuideline)
                        }
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 28.dp), elevation = 12.dp
                ) {
                    Column {
                        for (i in 1..15)
                            Text(text = "Account $i", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
                    }
                }

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(spacer) {
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        top.linkTo(accountList.bottom)
                    }
                    .padding(16.dp))

                LazyRow(modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(insightCards) {
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        top.linkTo(spacer.bottom)
                    }
                    .padding(start = 8.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
                ) {
                    items(10) {
                        Card {
                            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
                                Text(text = "Jetpack")
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                                Text(text = "Compose")
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```