# Why "remember" is not needed in the Canvas/Drawing context?

Tags: android, canvas, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, I learned that one needs to use `remember` to cache values between recompositions and that it is handy to use `MutableStates` to make such values "observables." (Ref: [this great thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65368007/)) That, in general, has worked as expected, but not when I use the `Canvas` composable.

For instance, the following code can update the rotation on the Canvas every time I click on it, even though I have not declared the `angle` as a cached nor as an observable state.

```
   DrawingTheme {
    var angle = 0f
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clickable {
                angle += 20
            }
    ) {
        rotate(
            degrees = angle
        ) {...}
    }
```

**Questions: Why is that?**

A1. Is it because the Canvas is not recomposed when the `onDraw` lambda is triggered, so the `angle` is not lost in the first place? Does that mean that the `clickable` modifier triggers the `onDraw`?

A2. Is it because the [`DrawScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope): "provides a declarative, stateless API to draw shapes and paths **without requiring consumers to maintain underlying Canvas state information**"? Does that mean any variable used in a DrawScope is automatically cached and observed?

Comment: My guess would be that this is working by coincidence.  Note that `angle` would be reset to `0f` if the outer `DrawingTheme` block were ever recomposed, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

`Canvas` is `Spacer` with `Modifier.drawBehind{}`

```
@Composable
fun Canvas(modifier: Modifier, onDraw: DrawScope.() -> Unit) =
    Spacer(modifier.drawBehind(onDraw))
```

Lambdas of Draw modifiers are invoked in draw phase recomposition. Modifier.clickable contains a state for interactions via MutableInteractionSource and on gesture events and invokes recomposition for the Modifier and it calls `Modifier.indication()` which triggers draw phase because of that draw phase of your Canvas is invoked as well. Since there is no recomposition in Composable scope value of angle never returns to 0.

[Why does mutableStateOf without remember work sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71045838/5457853)

In the question above since there is recomposition when a scope(MaterialTheme) is used  `mutableState` instance is not created same as in your question angle is never instantiated because there is no recomposition.

You can take this example for instance in which order draw Modifiers are called.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun CanvasTest() {
    var angle = 0
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(1f)
            .drawBehind {
                println("drawBehind1")

                rotate(angle.toFloat()) {
                    drawRect(
                        color = Color.Green,
                        topLeft = Offset((size.width - 200) / 2f, (size.width - 200) / 2f),
                        size = Size(200f, 200f)
                    )
                }
                angle += 20

            }

            .drawBehind {
                println("drawBehind2")

                rotate(angle.toFloat()) {
                    drawRect(
                        color = Color.Blue,
                        topLeft = Offset((size.width - 150f) / 2f, (size.width - 150f) / 2f),
                        size = Size(150f, 150f)
                    )
                }
                angle += 20

            }
    ) {
        println("I'm drawing too")
        rotate(angle.toFloat()) {
            drawRect(
                color = Color.Red,
                topLeft = Offset((size.width - 100) / 2f, (size.width - 100) / 2f),
                size = Size(100f, 100f)
            )
        }

        angle += 20
    }

}
```

[Jetpack Compose deferring reads in phases for performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457805/jetpack-compose-deferring-reads-in-phases-for-performance)

### Edit

If you call draw phase from another Canvas in another scope even then you will get draw phase called as in my question above.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun CanvasTest() {

    var angle = 0

    Column {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(1f)
        ) {
            println("I'm drawing")

            rotate(angle.toFloat()){
                drawRect(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    topLeft = Offset((size.width - 100) / 2f, (size.width - 100) / 2f),
                    size = Size(100f, 100f)
                )
            }

            angle += 20

        }

        OtherComposable()
    }
}

@Composable
private fun OtherComposable() {

    var counter by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable {
                counter += 20
            }
            .aspectRatio(1f)
    ) {
        println("I'm drawing too")
        drawRect(
            color = Color.Red,
            topLeft = Offset((size.width - 100) / 2f, (size.width - 100) / 2f),
            size = Size(100f, 100f)
        )
    }
}
```

You can also observe in this example draw phase of Composable in different scopes might also be invoked as well while there are no recompositions which can be tracked inside `SideEffect` functions.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun CanvasTest() {

    SideEffect {
        println("Recomposing...")
    }

    var angle = 0

    Column {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(1f)
        ) {
            println("I'm drawing")

            rotate(angle.toFloat()) {
                drawRect(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    topLeft = Offset((size.width - 100) / 2f, (size.width - 100) / 2f),
                    size = Size(100f, 100f)
                )
            }

            angle += 20

        }

        OtherComposable()
    }
}

@Composable
private fun OtherComposable() {

    SideEffect {
        println("Recomposing OtherComposable...")
    }

    var angle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while (angle < 360) {
            delay(100)
            angle+= 20
        }
    }


    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(1f)
    ) {
        println("I'm drawing too")
       rotate(angle.toFloat()){
           drawRect(
               color = Color.Red,
               topLeft = Offset((size.width - 100) / 2f, (size.width - 100) / 2f),
               size = Size(100f, 100f)
           )
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! So, what I am observing is a result of 1. the Canvas has never been recomposed because 2. the `clickable` in this case, smartly, only triggers the Drawing phase. I actually have a simple test of this where I added a `Text` together with the Canvas... without adding the "MutableState" to the angle, the Text is never updated but the Canvas is still rotated!

Comment: Yes, because there is no recomposition. And Modifier.clickable gets recomposed, yes Modifiers get composed when they read a `State`, and change in indication triggers draw phase for any Modifier assigned to Canvas. Check out my question, draw phase gets called even with other functions for some reason. Also add another function inside CanvasTest and trigger recomposition there and you will see that this Canvas will also draw again.

Comment: By the in second example it doesn't have to be Modifier.clickable. You can increase counter and if you read in Canvas lambda you will see that Canvas in CanvasTest calls draw phase as well for some reason. It's normal for a Modifier to call other draw Modifiers that assigned as in example on top. What's very strange draw phase of another Composable triggers somehow another ones either