# How to prevent unnecessary recomposition/redraw in Canvas

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I have a very simple app, that shows a list of numbers. It is supposed to mark the first visible item with a "+" inside the **TextB** composeable.

[image]

**TextA() =** Shows the index number of the list item *(has a random background color)*.
**MyCanvas() =** Has no input and just draws a rectangle with a random color.
**TextA() =** Reads the current state of firstVisibleIndex and checks it with the given parameter, If they are the same then shows a "+" *(has a random background color)*.

The below code works fine, but when **textB** reads the state and recomposes, also **MyCanvas** does an unnecessary recomposition!

```
val randomColor
    get() = Color(Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256))

@Composable
fun App() {

    val state = rememberLazyListState()
    val list = remember { (1..100).toList() }

    val firstVisibleItemIndex = remember(state) {
        derivedStateOf {state.firstVisibleItemIndex}
    }

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier,state = state
    ) {
        items(list.size) {
            Row {
                TextA(it)
                MyCanvas()
                TextB(it,firstVisibleItemIndex)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

**TextA() :**

```
@Stable
@Composable
fun TextA(i: Int) {
    Text(
        modifier= Modifier.size(80.dp,60.dp)
            .background(color = randomColor),
        text = "Index:$i")
}
```

**TextB() :**

```
@Stable
@Composable
fun TextB(index: Int, firstVisibleItemIndex: State<Int>) {
    val isFirstItem = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            index==firstVisibleItemIndex.value
        }
    }
    Text(
        modifier= Modifier.size(80.dp,60.dp)
            .background(color = randomColor),
        text = if (isFirstItem.value) "+" else ""
    )
}
```

**MyCanvas() :** // problem is here

```
@Stable
@Composable
fun RowScope.MyCanvas() {
    Canvas(modifier =Modifier.weight(1f).height(60.dp)
        .drawWithCache {
            onDrawBehind {
                drawRect(randomColor)
            }
        }
    ){}
}
```

And the result is this :
[image]

I search the stackoverflow and find **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71016788/7756492)** great answer by @Thracian. I tried it, and unfortunately, this is not the solution to my problem, **how should I prevent this behavior**?

Comment: I will test your answer when i'm available but i don't think what you see in Canvas is recompostion. Draw phase of sibling is called. If you wish to be sure print log inside `SideEffect` inside `MyCanvas` or set border with random color to Canvas

Comment: The question `Why DRAW phases of modifier3 and modifier4 are called when they are in a different Composable with scope? As you can see only PhasesSample1 is recomposed.` i asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457805/jetpack-compose-deferring-reads-in-phases-for-performance) might be the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyCanvas` is detecting overdraw, not over-composition. The `onDrawBehind` is called during drawing.

To avoid overdraw introduce a `graphicsLayer()` which notifies Compose that draw should be independent of the rest of the composition. For example, changing `MyCanvas` to:

```
@Composable
fun RowScope.MyCanvas() {
    Canvas(modifier =Modifier.weight(1f).height(60.dp)
        .graphicsLayer()
        .drawWithCache {
            onDrawBehind {
                drawRect(randomColor)
            }
        }
    ){}
}
```

will not draw when the text changes in the last column. Without a graphics layer the the two functions will share the same graphics layer which means that when one changes they both get redrawn. Normally the draw is not the bottleneck so sharing draw resources like this has better performance. However, there are cases where this is not true and you should use `graphicsLayer()` when it isn't.

If you want to detect over composition you can use `background()` as you did for `TextB` or generate the random color outside the `onDrawBehind` lambda such as,

```
@Composable
fun RowScope.MyCanvas() {
    val color = randomColor
    Canvas(modifier =Modifier.weight(1f).height(60.dp)
        .drawWithCache {
            onDrawBehind {
                drawRect(color)
            }
        }
    ){}
}
```

This generates a new random color when ever there is composition but not when there is a draw. It is still overdrawing but it is always drawing the same color until it is recomposed which is unlikely as it doesn't read mutable state.

Note also that `@Stable` is not necessary on these functions and is only meaningful on functions that return a value as it declares that, given a static parameter (i.e. will never change), the function's result is also static. This is the reason `Int.dp` is marked as stable. If the `Int` that `dp` is applied to is static, the result is also static. For example, `60` will never change as it is a literal,  therefore, since `dp` is marked `@Stable`, the compiler knows `60.dp` will also never change. This is used by the compiler to avoid storing and comparing values that will never change.

For `Unit` returning functions, this is a pointless annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The main culprit here is the random colour variable, which when accessed returns a new colour. So if you remove the get() part from the variable you will see only single colour for the whole lazyColumn.
Replace

```
val randomColor
get() = Color(Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256), 
Random.nextInt(256))
```

with

```
val randomColor = 
Color(Random.nextInt(256,Random.nextInt(256),Random.nextInt(256))
```

I don't know your usecase but i guess, you can create three random variable

```
val randomColor1 = Color(Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256),        
Random.nextInt(256))
val randomColor2 = Color(Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256), 
Random.nextInt(256))
val randomColor3 = Color(Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256), 
Random.nextInt(256))
```

and use accordingly your usecase.

Edit :[image: No Recompose]

Comment: I'm using random colors for detecting recompositions, I think you misunderstood the the question

Comment: and i don't see any recomposition of canvas except TextB()